# GSON list of list

Tags: java, json, gson

How do I deserialize a list of lists using Gson?

For example, given the following JSON string:

```
{
  vars: [
    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    [ 4, 5 ]
  ]
}
```

I can create the following two POJOs, to try and deserialize it:

```
class ThisDoesNotWork {
  public List<List<Integer>> vars;
}
```

Running `gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ThisDoesNotWork.class);` throws a `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException`.

But the following works (although it's not very usable):

```
class ThisWorks {
  public List<Object> vars;
}
```

If I attach a debugger to the output of `gson.fromJson(jsonStr, ThisWorks.class);`, I can see that the deserialized `vars` object contains:

```
vars = {java.util.ArrayList}, size = 2
|-- [0] = {java.util.ArrayList}, size = 3
     |-- [0] = {java.lang.Integer}, value = 1
     |-- [1] = {java.lang.Integer}, value = 2
     |-- [2] = {java.lang.Integer}, value = 3
|-- [1] = {java.util.ArrayList}, size = 2
     |-- [0] = {java.lang.Integer}, value = 4
     |-- [1] = {java.lang.Integer}, value = 5
```

So my question is, how do I correctly deserialize lists of lists using Gson?

Comment: Note that that's not a list of lists, it's a map of list of lists.

Comment: Yes, and that was (more or less) the problem in my code. Thanks :)

Comment: And if all you really want out of it is the lists, it's kind of silly to create a POJO for it.

Comment: Good point. This was however just to create a minimal example, my POJO has more attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a simple mistake on my part.

```
class ThisDoesWorkAfterAll {
  public List<List<Integer>> vars;
}
```

This **is** the correct way to deserialize the json. In my data, I simply had an additional level of lists. If you run into the same problem, check if GSON tells you it expected "Your Type" (E.g. Integer), but saw an START_ARRAY ([).

...embarrasing...